# Undeclared, uninitialised variables being used in expressions: what to think?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, initialization, variable-declaration

I'm struggling to understand the following code snippet (located in a file called `program.js`.
My issue is that I can't find where `CODERBOT_PROG_SAVEONRUN` is declared and/or initialized in this file.
No external code or library seems to be being imported.

I'm running into the same issue in many other places in [this](http://www.coderbot.org/en/index.html) particular [project](https://github.com/CoderBotOrg/coderbot).
Is this a quirky feature of JavaScript, or is there somewhere else I should be looking?

What should I think if a variable is used but not initialized and declared in a given JavaScript file?

Where is it coming from if there is no obvious "import" statement?

```
function runProg() {
    var bot = new CoderBot();
    // Generate JavaScript code and run it.
    window.LoopTrap = 1000;  
    Blockly.Python.INFINITE_LOOP_TRAP = '  get_prog_eng().check_end()\n';
    var code = Blockly.Python.workspaceToCode();

    if(CODERBOT_PROG_SAVEONRUN) {
        Blockly.Python.INFINITE_LOOP_TRAP = null;
        var xml_code = Blockly.Xml.workspaceToDom(Blockly.mainWorkspace);
        var dom_code = Blockly.Xml.domToText(xml_code);
        var data =  {'name': prog.name, 'dom_code': dom_code, 'code': code};
        try {
            $.ajax({url: '/program/save', data: data, type: "POST", success:function(){
                loadProgList();
            }});
        }catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
    try {
        var data =  {'name': prog.name, 'code': code};
        $.ajax({url: '/program/exec', data: data, type: "POST"});
        $("#dialogRunning").popup("open", {transition: "pop"});
        setTimeout(statusProg, 1000);
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, there is a global context, and local contexts defined by functions. If a variable is not defined inside a function, it is defined on a global context. In a browser, the global context is `window`; all scripts you run in that window share the same global context.

The variable you are looking for is defined in `templates/config_params.html`. Both it, and the `program.js` script are included from `templates/main.html`, which makes global variables of each visible to the other when displaying that page.

Comment: I have to wait 4 minutes to accept this answer. How the heck did you work that out so fast? XD I've been scratching my head at it for AGES

Comment: The first paragraph, by doing JS for a bit longer than 2 weeks. The second, using GitHub's search function. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is being initialized in this file:
https://github.com/CoderBotOrg/coderbot/blob/413491b566e675f8105b6494e3b80203c63d44c4/templates/config_params.html

I'm assuming that template is included at the top of the page, initializing all the constants such as `CODERBOT_PROG_SAVEONRUN`. This is one approach to exposing variables from the server to the client.